# Can we pass a command line argument to property file reader in jmeter

Tags: testing, properties, jmeter

I have a config.property file that contains all the property values to be used in jmeter, so i am using property file reader plugin to read the property file, here the problem is i don't want to hard code the path to config.properties file in property file reader so i want it to pass as command line argument but it is not working
[image]

[image]

command i am executing is

> .\jmeter -JPROPERTY_FILE=<file_location> -n -t <path_to_jmx> -l <path_to_jtl> -j <path_to_log>

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if it's ok, you should accept it and upvote so that others can use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the **File Path** of [Property File Reader](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/), replace:

> ${PROPERTY_FILE}

By using [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function:

> ${__P(PROPERTY_FILE)}

Your mistake is that you’re using Variable syntax for a property.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(PROPERTY_FILE)}` or even [__property() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) like `${__property(PROPERTY_FILE,PROPERTY_FILE)}`. The latter one automatically stores the retrieved value into a JMeter Variable so you won't have to additionally declare it under [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) of the [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
2. Instead of using custom plugins I would suggest going for built-in JMeter functionality, there is [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) which allows loading and arbitrary *.properties* file so you will not have to install the plugin, care about order of Configuration Elements, etc.